# SSH connection with Virtual Smart Card login

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel, smartcard

I'm using a virtual smart card in order to connect to a Windows remote server via RDP. When I do this it prompts me to insert a PIN, and so I'm done.
The account coupled to this smart card is an admin account, so I have to connect via SSH using this admin account.

How can I connect via SSH using this virtual smart card?

Comment: You have not provided very much information, have you asked, your IT Administrator how to accomplish this task?

Comment: @Ramhound thanks for the response. Unfortunately we've not full infrastructure control because is in the client's control. I don't think that I could provide very much details, because we actually work with this Virtual Smart card that we use to login through RDP. It prompts for the PIN and there you go

Answer (score 0):

I am successful at this using Pageant wincrypt (putty agent). I have tried it with physical and virtual SmardCards.
https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac/releases is the site to gather it from. It's pageant.exe and inside of https://github.com/NoMoreFood/putty-cac/raw/0.78u1/binaries/puttycac-64bit-0.78u1.zip

If you need help setting it up, tell me so.